# React Native - Save voice recording to remote database

Tags: php, mysql, react-redux, react-native

I am developing a mobile application using React Native and I am using the sound recording feature. Able to record audio and it's being saved in a folder in mobile "storage/emulated/0/recorded_audio.wav". But what I need is upon completing the record I want to call an API that would receive the audio file and save it to the database. Below is a sample code I am trying to do but it's not working.

```
 onStartRecord = async () => {
    RNVoiceRecorder.Record({
      onDone: (path) => {
        axios.post('MY_URL', {
          filePath: path,
          fileName: 'sample.wav'
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
   console.log(path);
      },
      onCancel: () => {

      }
  })
  }
```